# Connecting 14/3 off of 3 way switch to 14/2 line for new outlet

Tags: electrical

I have 14/3 going to a 3 way switch. The switch is the 2nd switch in a line that controls a ceiling fan.  I need to connect a 14/2 line to the 14/3 which will power a microwave outlet.  If that makes sense.

Comment: What’s your question? If there is more than 14-3 at the switch you will be able to do it if not you won’t have a neutral so you will need to pick up the power from some place else.

Comment: How many watts is the microwave, and is it a countertop microwave or a built-in appliance?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible for 2 reasons.

### You don't have the right wires there

The problem with (traditional) 3-way wiring is that you don't have the voltages you need in the places you need them.

[image]

*You need black, and white*.

Generally, in 3/4 way switch circuits, always-hot and neutral are *only* available at the location the power enters the circuit.  But if that was your setup, you wouldn't be asking for help, would you? :)

The cure for this half of the problem is smart switches.  They need either 1 or 0 traveler wires instead of 2, allowing you to reclaim black to be an always-hot.

### Kitchen receps can't serve anything else, and can't be 15A

Unless the microwave is a built-in, you are not allowed to install a receptacle in a kitchen unless it meets some rules.

- It must be 12 AWG and 20A breaker
- It must be a dedicated circuit that serves nothing but receptacles in the kitchen, pantry, dining room, breakfast nook etc.  (or ignitor/oven light on a gas oven, or a wall clock).

Since the circuit already powers a light, it can't add a kitchen receptacle to it.   Since the circuit is 15A, you cannot add a kitchen receptacle to it.

"But my existing wiring doesn't conform with that!"  Sure, that is **grandfathered** if the wiring was legal at the time it was installed.  However your new addition is not grandfathered and must comply with current Code.

The quasi-cure here is for the microwave to be a "built-in appliance" where the recep is behind the installed appliance and not accessible for any other purpose.